# Edit Nested Array of Objects in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Mongoose Model:

```
/** USER MODEL */
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            min: 5
        },
        wallets: [{
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            balance: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }

        }],
        transactions: [{
            type: {
                type: String,
                enum: ['expense', 'income']
            },
            label: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            amount: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            category: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            },
            wallet: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }],
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)
```

```
** THE CONTROLLER **

export const addTransaction = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const transaction = req.body.transaction
        const user = await User.findById(id)
        console.log(transaction.wallet)
        const wallet = await User.find(
            { "wallets.name": transaction.wallet })
        console.log(wallet)
        await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $push: { transactions:  
            transaction } })
        res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
    }
}
```

req.body.transaction has:

- amount // transaction amount that i want to subtract wallet balance with
- label // not needed in wallet calc
- wallet // the name of the wallet that needs to be accesed to change its balance

When a Transaction is made i get the Amount. I then need to subtract that amount from the wallets balance. Through req.body i get the walletname as well as the amount.

I need a mongoose query to find the wallet in User.wallets and edit its balance.

I have tried findByIdAndUpdate, find, findOne, findbyId, $set:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: {"wallets.amount": transaction.amount}}) 

User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { wallets: { name: transaction.wallet { amount: transaction.amount} }})
```

also the User.find function i used above in the controller returns the whole user but the wallets is : [[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]]

But i don't think i used em correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single `findOneAndUpdate` operation.

1. Find the user by `_id` and where `wallets.name` equal to `transaction.wallet`.
2. `$push` the `transaction` to the users `transactions` array.
3. `$inc`rement the `balance` on the array element matching the `$` positional operator found in the filter stage by a negative amount, effectively subtracting it.

```js
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
   {
      _id: id, 
     'wallets.name': transaction.wallet
   },
   {
      $push: {
         'transactions': transaction
      },
      $inc: {
         'wallets.$.balance': -transaction.amount    
      }
   },
   { new: true } 
);
```

See [HERE](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/2WXbEw7BZ1f) for a full working example.

The `findOneAndUpdate` can take an aggregation pipeline so you can perform more complex updates but since all you need to do is push to an array and deduct a value I've kept it simple.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, need to find the related `wallet` element from the `wallets` array and then set the new value to its `balance` field. For this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
{
  _id: id,
  "wallets.name": transaction.wallet
},
{
  $inc: {
    "wallets.$.balance": -transaction.amount
  }
})
```

Find the wallet filtering by its `name` field and `_id` field of the `User` model
Then update the **only first** found wallet element's `balance` field by using [Positional Operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/embedded-arrays/#std-label-first-match-operator) (`$`)

Here is the [DEMO Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VkPj0bDs_Ix) for the `single wallet update`

---

As another option, if you would like to update all the wallets which have the same `name`:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
{
  _id: id
},
{
  $inc: {
     "wallets.$[wallets].balance": -transaction.amount
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
     "wallets.name": transaction.wallet
    }
  ]
})
```

For multiple element updates, use [arrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6/#std-label-3.6-arrayFilters) to filter multiple elements
Then use [Filtered Positional Operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) (`$[<identifier>]` to update **all filtered wallet elements**.

Here is the [DEMO Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EUkuSa7e4SU) for the `multiple wallet update`

Hope, it's clear and helpful

Comment: does set no replace the balance by the amount, i want it to deduct.

Comment: I have missed that part. So, just need to use `$inc` instead of `$set` and edit `transaction.amount` as a minus to decrease the wallet balance. Updated my answer.